# Difference between UIInput#getValue() and getLocalValue() during validation

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, lifecycle

I would like to have an illustrative explanation about the difference between `getValue()` and `getLocalValue()` methods of [`UIInput` components](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) in the aspect of performing multiple field validation: [jsf validate two fields in one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478133/jsf-validate-two-fields-in-one-time).

What is the difference in usage of this methods if the fields are already validated? The [`ValueHolder` API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/ValueHolder.html) is not very helpful in answering this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the `UIInput` component has been validated beforehand and is marked invalid (i.e. `isValid()` method returns `false`), then the `getLocalValue()` returns `null`, but the `getValue()` returns the old model value, if any. If it's marked valid, then both returns the same value, namely the submitted, converted and validated value.

You'd like to add a check on `isValid()` beforehand. You may find the source code examples of the [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) multiple field validators helpful. See the [`ValidateMultipleFields`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/component/validator/ValidateMultipleFields.java) source code link at the bottom of the [`<o:validateEqual>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateEqual) showcase page.

#### See also:

- [JSF doesn't support cross-field validation, is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf2-0-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround)

Comment: when generally we should use getValue()? i saw in a blog that we "must use getValue() during encoding", is that the only place where we should use it ?

Comment: @Tarik: when it returns the value you actually need for the concrete functional requirement you had in mind but didn't tell about. The answer explains when exactly which value exactly it will return.

Comment: Ok so i understand that it depends on each functionnal case we have, but i can't see it clearly because for local values i know that they are setted after validation phase (if succeeded), but for values i dont know wich they are setted?

Comment: @Tarik: Oh, you mean the model values? That happens during update model values phase. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749451/difference-between-apply-request-values-and-update-model-values

Comment: i am talking about the values from uicomponent.getvalues ()

Comment: @Tarik: during validation. See also the current question, the "See also" link and the `UIInput` source code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691126/when-are-setvalue-and-setsubmittedvalue-called-on-uicomponent/

Comment: Sorry @BalusC, but when i saw the UIInput source code i more confused, i thought that after validation its localValue which must be set, now i see that in the validate method we are calling  setValue(newValue); so where we call the setLocalValue for UIInput ?

Comment: @Tarik: There's no `setLocalValue()`. The `setValue()` sets the local value (i.e. in component state), which gets reset during update model values phase (the `updateModel()` method). The `getValue()` returns the local value if set, else the model value. Again, see the source (and javadoc).

Comment: i didn't understood the source code , but now after your explanations i went back to the code and its very clear now.... thanks again :)

Comment: @BalusC: Could you elaborate on this line - "If the UIInput component has been validated beforehand...". Beforehand in plain english means IN ADVANCE.How can a component gets validated beforehand?

Comment: Beforehand means "before the current moment", in this context it means "has taken place in a previous postback request".

Comment: @BalusC: So to consolidate, isLocalValueSet() will be false, and getValue() will return the super.getValue() which is nothing but the model value. Right.

Comment: @Shirgil: keep in mind that submitted value, "is valid", local value and "is local value set" are saved in JSF view state. I.e. they are effectively view scoped.