# When are setValue and setSubmittedValue called on UIComponent?

Tags: jsf, components, lifecycle

If I correctly combined the information contained in BalusC's great 2006 post http://balusc.blogspot.ch/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html with Optimus Prime's even earlier post http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2005/12/28/jsf_component_s_value_local/ I get the following:

**My understanding:**

1. During the APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES phase,

   - the input value is set to a submittedValue property of the UI component (e.g. inputComponent.**setSubmittedValue**("test")).
2. During the PROCESS_VALIDATIONS phase,

   - the same values are read from the submittedValue property (presumably inputComponent.**getSubmittedValue**()) and used for conversion, if necessary.
   - If the conversion was successful or skipped, the result is set to a value property of the component (e.g. inputComponent.**setValue**("test")).
   - Also, the submittedValue is erased again immediately (e.g. inputComponent.**setSubmittedValue**(null))
   - the (converted) value is read from the value property of the UI component (presumably inputComponent.**getValue()**) and validated.
   - after validation, the backing bean/model's stored value is read (e.g. myBean.**getInputValue**()) and compared with the newly converted and validated value. If different, the valueChangeListener method(s) will be called.
3. During the UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES phase,

   - the newly converted and validated value is finally stored in the backing bean's property field (e.g. myBean.**setInputValue**("test")).

**Questions:**

- Is this correct?
- Is there something missing for a full understanding of what goes on between the POST and the saving of the input value in the backing bean?
- With immediate="true" on the Input Component, are we merely shifting these events to the APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES phase or do we change more than just the timing/order of events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost correct. The component's local value is only set when conversion **and** validation is successful. After that, the submitted value is set to `null`. You can find the entire process of the validations phase in a rather self-documenting way in the [`UIInput#validate()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/jsf-api/2.1/javax/faces/component/UIInput.java#UIInput.validate%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) method (line numbers are conform JSF 2.1 API):

```
934    public void validate(FacesContext context) {
935 
936         if (context == null) {
937             throw new NullPointerException();
938         }
939 
940         // Submitted value == null means "the component was not submitted
941         // at all".  
942         Object submittedValue = getSubmittedValue();
943         if (submittedValue == null) {
944             return;
945         }
946 
947         // If non-null, an instanceof String, and we're configured to treat
948         // zero-length Strings as null:
949         //   call setSubmittedValue(null)
950         if ((considerEmptyStringNull(context)
951              && submittedValue instanceof String 
952              && ((String) submittedValue).length() == 0)) {
953             setSubmittedValue(null);
954             submittedValue = null;
955         }
956 
957         Object newValue = null;
958 
959         try {
960             newValue = getConvertedValue(context, submittedValue);
961         }
962         catch (ConverterException ce) {
963             addConversionErrorMessage(context, ce);
964             setValid(false);
965         }
966 
967         validateValue(context, newValue);
968 
969         // If our value is valid, store the new value, erase the
970         // "submitted" value, and emit a ValueChangeEvent if appropriate
971         if (isValid()) {
972             Object previous = getValue();
973             setValue(newValue);
974             setSubmittedValue(null);
975             if (compareValues(previous, newValue)) {
976                 queueEvent(new ValueChangeEvent(this, previous, newValue));
977             }
978         }
979 
980     }
```

As to the `immediate` attribute on the `UIInput` component, yes this merely shifts the validation to the apply request values phase. See also the source code of [`UIInput#processDecodes()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/jsf-api/2.1/javax/faces/component/UIInput.java#UIInput.processDecodes%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) and [`UIInput#processValidators()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.faces/jsf-api/2.1/javax/faces/component/UIInput.java#UIInput.processValidators%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29), there's a check on `UIInput#isImmediate()`.