# How to print javascript alert message in p:message of primefaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

Javascript of my code

```
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirmPassword").value;

    if (password != confirmPassword){       
        alert("Passwords do not match!");
    }else{
        alert("Passwords match.");
    }
}
```

primefaces jsf code

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="matchGrid" cellpadding="5">                   
        <h:outputLabel for="pwd1" value="Password 1: *" />
        <p:password id="pwd1" value="password"  label="Password" required="true" />
        <p:message for="pwd1"/>


        <h:outputLabel for="pwd2" value="Password 2: *" />
        <p:password id="pwd2" value="confirmPassword" onkeyup ="checkPasswordMatch();" label="Confirm Password" required="true" />
        <p:message for="pwd2"/>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton update="matchGrid" value="Save" />
</h:form>
```

I want to print the alert message in p:message.. is it possible to do so..?? Please help

Comment: Please, be more descriptive in your question, there's no much to see in this code...

Comment: Hi Xtreme Biker.. I would like to change my code to as below.. but when I give the input for both password and confirm password.. still I get a message saying that the passwords dont match.              <h:outputLabel for="pwd1" value="Password 1: *" />
    <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{passwordView.password5}" label="Password 1" required="true" />

    <h:outputLabel for="pwd2" value="Password 2: *" />
    <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{passwordView.password5}" match="pwd1" label="Password 2" required="true" />
</h:panelGrid>

Comment: @NewUser You should edit your question. Posting so much code in a comment makes it very hard to read. ;)

Comment: The code as posted works correctly, i.e. matching passwords do match? Problem is, you want to move the `match` attribute to the second `p:password`, but it can't correctly match passwords then?

Comment: I have updated the code and the comment, can anyone please help me on that.. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use it like PrimeFaces User Guide tells you. The first `p:password` component must have the `match` attribute, not the second.

If the second `p:password` component has `match` defined then the following happens. When validating the first `p:password` its submitted value is deemed valid (which is already wrong in itself), so it gets set to null, and the local value is set. `p:password` match validation works by comparing submitted values. So when validating the second `p:password` it thinks that the first component was not filled at all, and declares mismatch.

More on local and submitted values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691126/when-are-setvalue-and-setsubmittedvalue-called-on-uicomponent).

Comment: @NewUser, click the checkmark to the left of the answer, it's right below the voting arrows.