# JSF2 custom tag : setValue method never call

Tags: jsf-2.2, custom-tag

I wrote a JSF2 custom tag extended `UIInput`class:

```
<custom:param lang="fr" disabled="#{search.disabled}"
styleClass="#{search.styleClass}"
style="width: 95px"
value="#{search.value}" />
```

And I want to evaluate the value like this :

```
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty((String) this.getSubmittedValue())) {
  if (valeur.getCode().equals(this.getSubmittedValue())) {
    writer.writeAttribute("selected", "selected", null);
  }
} else {
  if (valeur.getCode().equals(this.getValue())) {
    writer.writeAttribute("selected", "selected", null);
  }
}
```

Everything works fine but the `setValue` method of `UIInput` class is never call.

I overrided the `setValue`method of `UIInput` class with :

```
@Override
public void setValue(Object value) {
  if (((String)value).startsWith("#")) {
    getStateHelper().put(ParametrageTag.ATTRIBUT_VALUE, (String) value);
  } else {
    this.value = (String)value;
  }
}
```

I put a breakpoint but this method is never call. The `value` attibute is always `null`.

I don't understand what is wrong because all other attribute of my custom tag are correctly setted.

There is a special way to obtain the `value` attribute ?

Comment: did you tried to add a h:messages to your page? if there is some conversion / validation errors then JSF will skip the Update Model Phase

Comment: There is a h:messages in my page.

Comment: I don't think you even need to override the satValue method, could you test if your value isValid using `isValid()`? I think this Q&A would be very useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948831/difference-between-uiinputgetvalue-and-getlocalvalue-during-validation

Comment: Thanks a lot. The link helped me. Everything works now.