# Why this line [isLocalValueSet() ? getLocalValue(): ...] instead of [isLocalValueSet() ? getValue(): ...] in UIInput class?

Tags: jsf, input, lifecycle

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948831/difference-between-uiinputgetvalue-and-getlocalvalue-during-validation), but the answer is not very clear to me. Hence asking,

For the validate method of the class `UIInput`, we have this (Marking only those lines which are related to the question)

```
public void validate(FacesContext context) {

     Object submittedValue = getSubmittedValue();           // LINE 958

     newValue = getConvertedValue(context, submittedValue); // LINE 976

     validateValue(context, newValue);                      // LINE 983

     if (isValid()) {                                       // LINE 987
            Object previous = getValue();
            setValue(newValue);                             // LINE 989
            setSubmittedValue(null);
     }
}
```

If both Conversion & Validation succeeds, then `isValid()` returns `true`.

The component's `local` value is then set - `setValue(newValue)`, indicated by the flag `setLocalValueSet(true)`

After that, the `submitted` value is set to null - `setSubmittedValue(null)`

If you look at the code for this setValue(...) method of UIInput, it is overridden,

```
@Override
public void setValue(Object value) {
    super.setValue(value);
    // Mark the local value as set.
    setLocalValueSet(true);
}
```

So from LINE 989, the call delegated to this above setValue(...).
If you look at this method,

```
@Override
public Object getValue() {
    return isLocalValueSet() ? getLocalValue() : super.getValue();
}
```

If the local value was set by setValue(...), indicated by the flag `setLocalValueSet(true)`,
why is this returning the getLocalValue()?
I mean,

```
isLocalValueSet() ? getLocalValue() : ....
```

Why is it not

```
isLocalValueSet() ? getValue() : ....
```

As seen through above, my confusion is regarding `getValue()` & `getLocalValue()` methods. Furthermore, in which case `Object previous = getValue();` will be `not null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *If the local value was set by setValue(...), indicated by the flag setLocalValueSet(true), why is this returning the getLocalValue()?*

I think it's helpful to read javadoc of [`ValueHolder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/ValueHolder.html) interface.

> `Object getLocalValue()`
>
> Return the local value of this `UIComponent` (if any), **without** evaluating any associated `ValueExpression`.

> `Object getValue()`
>
> Gets the value of this `UIComponent`. If validation failed, as indicated by `FacesContext.isValidationFailed()` returning `true`, always return the local value. Otherwise, first, consult the local value property of this component. If non-`null` return it. If `null`, see if we have a `ValueExpression` for the value property. If so, return the result of evaluating the property, otherwise return `null`.

> `void setValue(Object value)`
>
> Set the value of this `UIComponent` (if any).

Note my emphasis on "without".

In other words, `getLocalValue()` and `setValue()` form a true getter/setter pair, basically referring component's own instance variable, not the bean property behind any expression specified in component's `value` attribute such as `value="#{bean.value}"`.

The `getValue()` method is implemented in such way that it auto-evaluates any associated `ValueExpression` when validation hasn't failed (yet) and the local value is `null`. This is undesireable when the (converted) submitted value is actually `null` and the component is still busy processing the validations phase and the model values haven't been updated yet.

Simply put, if `getValue()` were used instead of `getLocalValue()`, then the case "user removed (non-required) input value" would fail as `getValue()` returns the initial model value.

---

> *Furthermore, in which case Object previous = getValue(); will be not null?*

When there's an initial value in the model.

Comment: You mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642242/how-can-i-populate-a-text-field-using-primefaces-ajax-after-validation-errors-oc that [When JSF validation fails for a particular input component during the validations phase, then the submitted value is kept in the input component.]i.e the local value wasn't set(i.e setValue(...)in validatemethod is not c/d). Whereas, as above for getValue(), its written that  If validation failed, as indicated by FC.isValidationFailed()returning true, always return the local value. If the validation failed, whythen return the local value.

Comment: When validations phase has failed due to a conversion or validation error anywhere, components which successfully passed validation will return local value and components which failed validation will return submitted value.

Comment: But the javadoc for getValue() is confusing me.If validation failed[THIS WILL BE FOR A PARTICULAR COMPONENT], as indicated by FacesContext.isValidationFailed() returning true, always return the local value. They haven't said return the SUBMITTED VALUE.

Comment: The submitted value is accessed via `getSubmittedValue()`. Do note that this happens during render response phase only.

Comment: The validate method is c/d in PROCESS VALIDATIONS PHASE. the submitted value is getting accessed here- Object submittedValue = getSubmittedValue(); To explain you further, I have raised this-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36907050/uiinputgetvalue-and-getlocalvalue-after-validation-succeeds-return-differen

Comment: The link in your first comment describes the logic "first submitted value, then local value, then model value" in relationship to logic during generating HTML output, not to logic of `getValue()` method.