# Why does isLocalValueSet() returns true in this case?

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, lifecycle

Consider the snippet:

```
<f:metadata>
        <f:viewAction onPostback="true" 
                      action="#{simpleBean.action}" 
                      phase="PROCESS_VALIDATIONS">
        </f:viewAction>
      </f:metadata>
    <h:head>
        <title></title>
    </h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText 
                    value="#{simpleBean.inputValue}" 
                    binding="#{simpleBean.htmlInputText}" 
                    validator="nameValidator" /><br/>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{simpleBean.action}" />
        </h:form>
</h:body>
```

with view action method just printing the bounded component properties.

```
        System.out.println(" getSubmittedValue() "+htmlInputText.getSubmittedValue());
        System.out.println(" isLocalValueSet() "+ htmlInputText.isLocalValueSet());
        System.out.println(" getValue() " + htmlInputText.getValue());
        System.out.println(" getLocalValue() " +htmlInputText.getLocalValue());
```

Case1)

> If it's[COMPONENT] marked valid, then both returns the same value,
>   namely the submitted, converted and validated value.

When one enters a value of 68 in the text field & submits-

```
 getSubmittedValue() null
 isLocalValueSet() true
 getValue() 68
 getLocalValue() 68
```

Case2)

> If the UIInput component has been validated beforehand and is marked
>   invalid (i.e. isValid() method returns false), then the
>   getLocalValue() returns null, but the getValue() returns the old model
>   value, if any

When one enters an incorrect value like `54@`

```
 getSubmittedValue() 54@
 isLocalValueSet() false
 getValue() 5
 getLocalValue() null
```

I perfectly understood the 2 above cases,
Here's a slightly different test case:

Case3)

> Enter a valid value first time
>
> Submit
>
> Enter an incorrect value
>
> Submit

```
 getSubmittedValue() null
 isLocalValueSet() true
 getValue() 68
 getLocalValue() 68

 getSubmittedValue() 90@
 isLocalValueSet() true     // WHY is this TRUE, even when validation failed
 getValue() 68              // WHY THESE PREVIOUS VALUES
 getLocalValue() 68         // WHY THESE PREVIOUS VALUES
```