# JSF managed bean naming conventions

Tags: jsf, naming-conventions, managed-bean

These days I used to work with JSF, but there's a "convention" I'm in doubt if I should use. While working with managed beans, people used to name it as `XxxxxManagedBean` where the prefix can be any name related to your business.

Have you worked like that? Particularly, I don't like that much despite makes search easy. Are you using another convention?

Thanks for answering this simple doubt.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no strict convention specified by JSF itself. I've seen the following conventions:

- `FooBean`
- `FooBacking`
- `FooManager`
- `FooController`
- `FooManagedBean`

Or even just `Foo` which is then placed in a specific package like `com.example.controller`, `com.example.backing` or even `com.example.view`, etc.

I myself tend to use `FooManager` for application and session scoped beans (e.g. `DataManager`, `UserManager`, `LocaleManager`, etc) and just `Foo`, or as mandated by my current project, `FooBacking` (e.g. `Login` or `LoginBacking`) for request and view scoped beans, which are each usually tied to a specific `<h:form>` and/or view.

`FooBean` is too vague. Really a lot of classes can be marked as javabeans. JSF managed beans, JPA entities, EJBs, data transfer objects, value objects, etc. The `Bean` naming does not indicate the real responsibility of the class in any way. True, I use [often](https://google.com/search?q=balusc%20%22public%20class%20Bean%22) `public class Bean` or `MyBean` in my generic code examples in blogs or forum/Q&A answers, but in real world you should avoid that.

`FooManagedBean` is IMO a poor name, it's not only too long and ugly, but technically, a managed bean is an *instance* of a backing bean which is managed by some framework (JSF in this case). [The class definition itself is really a backing bean, not a managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713483/difference-between-managed-bean-and-backing-bean/34030260#34030260). So a `FooBackingBean` is technically more correct, but it's still too long and the `Bean` part is a bit itchy.

Anyway, this is a pretty subjective question which can hardly be answered objectively with The One And Correct answer. It really doesn't matter that much to me or anyone else what you makes of it, as long as you're consistent with it throughout the entire project.

Comment: I have seen people use FooMB as a shortcut for FooManagedBean

Comment: As a rule of thumb, try to use non-technical names. It's obvious from the context your bean is a managed bean, so don't call it `xxxManagedBean`. Or rather: don't concentrate on the second part of the name. The important part is `xxx`. `SomeFormBean` is a worse name than `PersonFormBean`, which is worse than `CreditUserBean`. You get the idea: the latter name tells you something about what the bean is all about. And that's what helps you on the long run.

Comment: could we name FooView as primefaces do? or am I wrong?