# SessionScoped bean implementation and naming convention

Tags: jsf, architecture, javabeans

I've just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746047/jsf-backing-bean-structure-best-practices) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223055/making-distinctions-between-different-kinds-of-jsf-managed-beans/7223910#7223910) post to get an idea of how to organize my application. Regarding to the Entity part, there is something unclear to me.

The first post says, to have a session bean entity, to store the data for a user session. I don't like the idea, because I want to have an Entity class only for representing the database structure.

The second post says, it should be used like a pojo in the backing bean, which I like more. But my question is, where to have the session bean to store the current data.

So far I have:

- A CDI backing bean (package: com.myapp.backingbeans)
- A request scoped DAO bean which is injected into the backing bean (package: com.myapp.dao)
- An Entity class which is instantiated in the backing bean (package: com.myapp.entities)

Is there a convention how to name the package or bean which should preserve the current session data? It doesn't belong to any of the above, it isn't a controller and I wouldn't say, that it's not a "helper".

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697351

Comment: Thanks for the link! I think the session bean that holds the current states of data for the users will by its functionality fit in a "manager" package. In case the name "manager" isn't usually used for something complete different?