# JSF : ManagedBean, Good place to deal with Business Logic?

Tags: java, jsf, faces-config

I have `managedBean` for `fileUpload`, once file is uploaded then i need to call different parsers based on what value is selected from the parser dropdown and then in parser am creating object of `DetailsClass` where am calling `getDetails` method for that particular class, thing to note here is that neither `parserClass` nor `DetailsClass` is registered in faces-config.xml, my question here is

- If i want to maintain session information from `FileUpload` class to `Parser` class to `DetailsClass` then I should be defining it in `faces-config.xml` but how should `parser` class and `DetailsClass` be defined, should it be defined as `managedBean` or like something else?

Here is the code:

In my managedBean class i have two function, `fileUpload` and `callParser` as shown:

```
 public void uploadFile(FileEntryEvent event)
{
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    //Setting getSession to false, container will not create new session if session is not present and return null
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) ctx.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    setSession(session);

    resultBean = new ResultBean();
    FileEntry fileEntry = (FileEntry) event.getSource();
    FileEntryResults results = fileEntry.getResults();
    FileEntry fe = (FileEntry) event.getComponent();

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage();
    for (FileEntryResults.FileInfo fileInfo : results.getFiles())
    {
        if (fileInfo.isSaved())
        {
            File file = fileInfo.getFile();
            String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            callParser(selectedItem, filePath);
        }
        resultBeanList.add(resultBean);
    }
}

private void callParser(String parserType, String filePath)
{
    if ("Delta".equals(parserType))
    {
        PositionParserDelta deltaParser = new PositionParserDelta();
        deltaParser.getQuotes(filePath);
    }
    else if ("Gamma".equals(parserType))
    {
        PositionParserGamma gammaParser = new PositionParserGamma();
        gammaParser.getQuotes(filePath);
    }
}
```

Now, let say we consider `Delta Parser`, so in that class I have something like:

```
public class PositionParserDelta extends Base
{
    List<String[]> dataList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    ContractManager contractManager = new ContractManager();

    public PositionParserDelta()
    {
    }

    public void getQuotes(String fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            Map<String, ContractSeries> gsLookup = contractManager.getContractsMap(ContractManager.VendorQuotes.KRT);
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), '\t');
            String[] header = reader.readNext();
            dataList = reader.readAll();
            List<Trade> tradeBeanList = new ArrayList<Trade>();
            for (String[] data : dataList)
            {
                //Some Business Logic
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My `contractManager` Class looks like

```
    public class ContractManager extends Base
    {
        private List<Series> List = new ArrayList<Series>();
        private ContractSeries[] SeriesList = new Series[3];
        private ListingOps listingOps;

//This line throws error as faces class not found and it makes sense because am not registering this with faces-config.xml
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);

        public List<ContractSeries> getContracts(long orgId, HttpSession session)
        {
            log.info("Inside getContracts method call");
            if (false)
            {
                //Some Logic
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    //Set session and get initialContext to retrieve contractSeries data from ejb calls
                    log.info("Trying to get allContractSeries data from listingOpsBean");
                    Series[] allSeries = deltaOps.findAllSeries(true);
                    Collections.addAll(contractList, allContractSeries);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
            return contractList;
        }

        public Map<String, ContractSeries> getContractsMap(VendorQuotes vendorQuotes)
        { //Some Logic
    }
```

But in faces-config.xml file,

```
 <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>fileUpload</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>trade.UploadBlotterBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

So basically my question is,

> if suppose am calling other classes from `managedBean` then how should
>   they be defined in `faces-config.xml` and since am new to `JSF`, is
>   calling other classes from `managedBean` and having some business
>   logic in those classes considered good practice?

Also i need to make sure that i maintain session that i obtain in `UploadFile` across `Parser` and `ContractMapping` class.

Also,

> Is everything is 'registered' as managed-bean in faces-config ?

Comment: Is my question clear or there is some confusion, let me know and I can add more meat to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but I think every bean is registered as `<managed-bean>` in `faces-config`. On the specific role, a class plays, they can be categorized into

1. `Model Managed-Bean`
2. Backing Managed-Bean
3. Controller Managed-Bean
4. Support Managed-Bean
5. Utility Managed-Bean ...

By giving them appropriate name you can distinguish them in `faces-config`. As per the work served by bean , set there scopes.

Comment: Ok, what is the difference between `managedBean` and `managedProperty`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713483/difference-between-managed-bean-and-backing-bean