# JSF managedbean has variables with different scope

Tags: jsf, scope, javabeans, managed

I have some variables in JSF managedbean with different scopes (that I feel).
In the following snippet, **userTable** is used in both **login()** and **register()** method.
But **roleList** is used only in register() method.

**userTable** should be in session scope, since it should be accessable during user session.

And I feel like **roleList** should not be in session scope, since it will be populated in a combo box during registration page only. I guess request scope is enough.

But how can I put roleList in requestScope since UserManagedBean is in session scope already.

Thanks much for any advice.

```
@Named("user")
@Scope("session")
public class UserManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private UserTable userTable = new UserTable(); 
    private List roleList = new ArrayList();

    public String login() {
     // login process here
    }

    public String register() {
     // register user here
    }
```

Comment: why don't you create another managed bean of request scope, and use it in registration page ? I think, user will use registration page once for registration

Comment: Are you sure you really need to inject another managed bean in this one or you're thinking about `UserTable` as your business logic class?

Comment: I am thinking about it too. But what if there are two variables with different scopes in one method (e.g in register())?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza UserTable is just a POJO, no business logic.

Comment: Then don't worry about it. You don't have a managed bean inside another. Refer to [Difference between managed bean and backing bean](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4713564/1065197) to understand what is a managed bean.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I don't get you. Sorry I am very new to JSF. In servlet, we can put any variable in any scope. Now in managed bean, I am thinking I cannot define the scope of variable individually.

Comment: Please go through a JSF tutorial that explains from the basic concepts since you have lot of misconceptions. There are good tutorial links on [StackOverflow JSF wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

Comment: yes I think you should follow Luiggi advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the concrete question, just split the bean in 2 separate beans. As you're apparently managing beans by Spring instead of by JSF or CDI for some unclear reason, you can use `@Autowired` to inject the one bean as a property of the other bean.

```
@Named
@Scope("request")
public class Login implements Serializable {

    private List<Role> roles;

    @AutoWired
    private User user;

    public String submit() {
         UserTable userTable = user.getTable();
         // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

```java
@Named
@Scope("session")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private UserTable table;

    // ...
}
```

If you were managing the beans by JSF `@ManagedBean`, you could use `@ManagedProperty` for that. If you were managing the beans by CDI `@Named`, you could use `@Inject` for that.

---

Coming back to the concrete functional requirement,

> And I feel like roleList should not be in session scope, since it will be populated in a combo box during registration page only. I guess request scope is enough.

That's a pretty weak reason. If it were me, I'd have placed it in the application scope. The role list is the same for every single request/session anyway, right? You don't need to reload/repopulate it on every request then, unless you've a really, really low memory footprint.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)

Comment: That is a very good answer. So I should split the beans. Is it possible to have instance variables with different scope in a single ManagedBean? I used to think that login, register, logout functions are related to User, thats why I should put all these functions in a single UserManagedBean. Is there any good practices to split the functions and managed beans? Absolutely roleList should be in application scope for my case. Thanks much.

Comment: That's tight coupling. For starters, use a separate request/view scoped bean per `<h:form>`. It'll automagically end up in clean code. Note that I've updated my answer with a link "How to choose the right bean scope?", I recommend to give it a read.

Comment: I read somewhere that by using JSR330 in Spring, I could reuse that managedbean in another CDI environment. Thats why I am mixing Spring with JSR330. Do you have any comment on that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Spring anyway. Just the standard Java EE stack. I just use EJB instead of Spring services and CDI instead of Spring DI and `@Interceptor` instead of Spring AOP. Spring was nice during the J2EE ages when EJB was terrible and CDI didn't exist. Java EE 5/6 learnt and incorporated a lot of lessons of Spring which makes Spring superfluous. Even more, Spring is considered "legacy" nowadays. It even ends up in more XML boilerplate than Java EE.