# PrimeFaces multiple DataTables and rowselect event

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a dynamic list of data tables and I need to enable row selection for a single row of each table.
The code below works only if the user selects a row of the last data table, maybe because the Ajax event is replaced and only last event works.

If the user selects a row from another data table, onRowSelect method is called but there is a `NullPointerException` on variable `selectedRow`.

Maybe I need to create multiple onrowselect method in Java bean,one for each data table, but the number of this table is variable.

How can I solve this issue?

```html
<c:forEach items="#{azPerformancePrenPubAll.selectedCompanyTemp}" var="companyCode" varStatus="loop">
  <p:accordionPanel id="acc_#{companyCode}" widgetVar="accordionAziendale_#{companyCode}" activeIndex="-1"> 
    <p:tab title="#{azPerformancePrenPubAll.selectedCompanyName.get(loop.index)}">             
       <p:dataTable id="tablePerformance_#{companyCode}" rendered="#{!azPerformancePrenPubAll.isCompanyVisible}"
                    widgetVar="tablePerformance" var="performance" value="#{azPerformancePrenotatiPubAll.listPerformances.get(loop.index)}" 
                    styleClass="perfDataTable no-border" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" 
                    selectionMode="single" selection="#{azPerformancePrenPubAll.selectedRow}" rowKey="#{performance.id}">
         <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{azPerformancePrenPubAll.onRowSelect}" update="formPerformance,pageSubDescription,pageDescription"/>
         ...
```

Comment: I don't see a variable `RowSelected`

Comment: @JasperdeVries sorry I misspelled the variable name, I edited the post.  the variable is specified in the selection attribute of the datatable, it's 'selectedRow'

Comment: You are using mutliple tables and you renamed the `id` field but you have an identical widgetVar for all your tables `widgetVar="tablePerformance"` which is not allowed.  WidgetVar must be unique per widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a common `selectedRow` variable in the loop might cause the `NullPointerException` if the user selects a row from a data table other than the last one.

You could try and create a Map in your [backing bean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35354083/6309) to hold the `selectedRow` for each `companyCode`.

```java
private Map<String, YourDataType> selectedRows = new HashMap<>();
```

And then in your XHTML:

```html
selection="#{azPerformancePrenPubAll.selectedRows[companyCode]}"
```

In addition, you can also pass the `companyCode` or any other unique identifier to the method in the listener.

```html
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{azPerformancePrenPubAll.onRowSelect(companyCode)}" />
```

In your Java bean:

```java
public void onRowSelect(String companyCode) {
    // Logic here
}
```

As you are using `widgetVar="tablePerformance"`, make sure this is also unique for each loop iteration.

---

> Using unique widgetVar works, I still use only a variable selectedRow

If you have confirmed that using a unique `widgetVar` solves the problem while still using a single `selectedRow` variable, you may amend the answer as follows:

You could address the issue of `NullPointerException` by ensuring that each data table component has a unique `widgetVar`. That will allow each table to operate independently on the client side, preventing any overwrite of the `selectedRow`.

```html
widgetVar="tablePerformance_#{companyCode}"
```

By making the `widgetVar` unique, the single `selectedRow` variable can be updated correctly regardless of which table triggers the `rowSelect` event.

That simplifies your backing bean, as there is no need to maintain a map for each `companyCode` or handle multiple `onRowSelect` methods. It meets the functional requirements and is a clean solution.

Comment: thank you, using unique widgetVar works, I still use only a variable selectedRow